# Get POST variable using wildcard or regex

Tags: php

How to get POST variable using regex like this:

```
$var = $_POST['foo?'];
```

or

```
$var = $_POST['foo\w{1}'];
```

Edit:

My form has many buttons with separate names: file1, file2, file3. When pressing a button, of course it pass file1 or file2, ... I want to get the value using that name.

Comment: Please provide more context on what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing I can think of is this:

```
$allPostKeys = implode(',',array_keys($_POST));
$wildcardVals = array();
if (preg_match_all('/,?(foo[0-9]),?/',$allPostKeys,$matches))
{
    $wildCardKeys = $matches[1];
    while($key = array_shift($wildCardKeys))
    {
        $wildcardVals[$key] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}
if (!empty($wildcardVals))
{//do stuff with all $_POST vals that you needed
}
```

Replace `[0-9]` in the regex with `.` to match *any* char, or whatever you need to see matched.
Tested this out with an array that had the following keys `bar,zar,foo1,foo2,foo3`, and it returned `array('foo1' => 'val1','foo2' => 'val2','foo3' => 'val3')`, which is what you need, I think.

*In response to your edit*
The `$_POST` super-global can be a multi dimensional array, too:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file1"/>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file2"/>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file3"/>
```

That way, you can easily loop through the files:

```
foreach($_POST['file'] as $file)
{
    //process each file individually: $file is the value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

run in a loop through the array, and check on the keys

like:

```
// some POST: array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'cc11' => 6666666)

foreach( $_POST as $k => $v ) {
   if ( preg_match('#^[^\d]+$#', $k) ) { // not number key 
      // you actions ...
   }
}
```

Comment: But how to get the value of it?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to loop through the $_POST array:

```
$regex = "@foo\w{1}@";
$vars = array();

foreach($_POST as $name=>$value) {
    if(preg_match($regex, $name)) {
        $vars[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you could do this:

```
<?php
    $_POST = array(
        "foo" => "bar",
        "file1" => "something",
        "file2" => "somethingelse",
        "file3" => "anothervalue",
        "whocares" => "aboutthis"
    );
    $files = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (preg_match("/file(\d+)/", $key, $match)) {
            $files[$match[1]] = $value;
        }
    }
    print_r($files);
?>
```

Output (where the key matches file[**NUMBER**]):

```
Array ( 
    [1] => something 
    [2] => somethingelse 
    [3] => anothervalue 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Name your form fields as array data structures:

```
<input name="files[]" ...>

foreach ($_POST['files'] as $file) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for common sense, amazing everybody else got +1 despite the convoluted and needlessly complex answers

Comment: doesn't work with named keys like `files[0]` or files[1]. that's why i'm here unfortunately, my front end application relies on the keys having a distinct value.

Comment: @r3wt It should work with names like `files[0]`, since that should be creating an array `files` with keys `0`, `1` etc...!?

Comment: @deceze i should have mentioned that i'm Using Slim Framework, so i'm not using the superglobal `$_POST`, but rather the method `$app->request->post();` so they use the raw http headers.